# GA bigquery page views by page title

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am a GA premium user and new to bigquery. I am doing some data exploration and want to pull page views by title. I don't think you can do something like the following query because the totals.pageview records are an aggregate already:

```
SELECT hits.page.pageTitle, sum(totals.pageviews) FROM [sample.ga_sessions_20150125]
GROUP BY hits.page.pageTitle
```

Can someone explain how I can recreate pulling pageviews from raw hits data? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, `totals` contains aggregate values across the visit of the visitor, so the context for those numbers is the visitor.

```
SELECT hits.page.pageTitle,
       count(DISTINCT fullVisitorId)
FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910]
GROUP BY hits.page.pageTitle
```

this query calculates the unique visitors per page.

You can run the above query on [BigQuery sample dataset](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416091?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there a similar field to do a count distinct to get page views?

Comment: @amysong you can filter by `hits.type='PAGE'`

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, okay, I got it. I used:

```
select hits.page.pageTitle, count(*)
from [sample.ga_sessions_20150125]
where hits.type='PAGE'
group by hits.page.pageTitle
```

Just needed the hits.type value, and to not use the totals number. Thanks!